# Soql query for self lookup on account

Tags: apex, soql

Trying to get a sub-query within the Account trigger.
Account has a lookup to itseff self in field entity__c How do i get the entity__c records related to the parent account i tried the above soql but no luck
i tried in query editor and it says no such e

Account has a self lookup field: `entity__c`. I am checking for a condition: `date__c > today` in entity__c is found

How do I get the fields from the `entity__c` related to it's parent Account record? I have tried SOQL(below) but didn't seem to work.

```
Select id,(SELECT Id,Name,date__c From Account where RecordtypeId= '0121N003401DbNk'),entity__r From Account
```

Comment: This is a similar problem to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291009/didnt-understand-relationship-attachment-in-from-part-of-query-call and I think my answer on that question would help you with yours. Also "it doesn't work" is usually not sufficient for a description of the issue. If you're getting an error message, it's always a good idea to include the full text of the error (don't paraphrase it).

Comment: Account has a lookup to itseff self in field entity__c
How do i get the entity__c records related to the parent account
i tried the above soql but no luck

Comment: To Derek's point, his answer has all you need. Use the anonymous apex to figure out the child relationship name on the self-lookup and go from there.

Comment: I tried this 
select id, Entity__r.Id  from Account where RecordtypeId= '0121N000001jsNk' AND Entity__r.Date__c > System.TODAY()

AND condition is throwing error as error parsing query

how do we write this

Comment: `Entity__r.Date__c > :System.TODAY() ` - you need a bind variable notation if using apex; if straight SOQL you need to use a date literal (see doc)